# I want to reset every radiobutton to unchecked, but my code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, selectors-api

I am trying to get a challenge done, for a javascript course.
 After the click on a button, I want to uncheck every checked radiobutton. Below is my code:

```
let result = 0;
function checkResult() {
  if (document.getElementById("quiz1a").checked == true) {
      result++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("quiz2c").checked == true) {
      result++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("quiz3a").checked == true) {
      result++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("quiz4a").checked == true) {
      result++;
  }
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').checked = false;
  console.log(result);
  result = 0;
}
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns an array of elements, so it wont has a single checked value. You should run a `forEach` loop for each element in that array.

Comment: @ThomasScheffer I assume you meant `querySelectorAll`, which technically returns a NodeList, not an Array. (Depending on what one wants to do with the result, this either doesn't matter at all or does matter a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
```

Returns an array. You should iterate over its elements using `forEach`.

As this is for a course, I won't spell it out for you ;)

Comment: @Jimmy Sry, I was in the middle of moving my comment up to the original post when you responded, so I accidentally made it look like your response is pointing to Jonas' answer.